# Finding all pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers such that $a^2+nab+b^2$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

When $n=2$, the question is trivial. Is there a general method to find all such pairs for $n\ge{3}$ and $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Well if $a^2+nab+b^2=k^2$ then $(n-2)ab=(k-a-b)(k+a+b) $ and $(n-6)ab=(k-a+b)(k+a-b) $.  Don't know if the helps.

Comment: In other words, we are looking for triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that $a^2 + b^2 + nab = c^2$, correct?

Comment: Might have to investigate the norm in the number field $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{n^2-4}]$ ...

Comment: Not really a reasonable question for arbitrary $n.$ The condition of positive integers is not especially good unless $n < 0.$ Put another way: why do you want to know this?

Comment: @WillJagy Why isn't this a reasonable question (I genuinely don't know enough about number theory that this is obvious to me)? Also, what do you mean "the condition of positive integers is not especially good unless $n < 0$. If $n < 0$, what condition of positive integers is there if $n < 0$? Also—and a bit facetiously—how is asking "why do you want to know this?" putting the other two objections in another way? It seems like a completely different question.

Comment: @WillJagy Is it not a reasonable question because there are too many variables? That is, being able to alter $n, a,$ and $b$ freely kind of make the question too mathematically vague?

Comment: @AmagicalFishy the short version: this seems about improving a computer algorithm rather than mathematics itself. The behavior of this changes pretty violently based on $n$

Comment: @avs Yes, you are right.

Comment: @WillJagy Finding all such pairs in the case of $n=10$ will help with a problem I've been working on (please rest assured that it is NOT my homework).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Would you mind providing an example for a specific case (say, when $n=3$)?

Comment: Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_triple

Comment: @Shu_HE:  Rather than "correct" the algebra in the posted Answer, you should probably raise your concerns with the Answer's author in Comments there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a^2+nab+b^2 = c^2$

Let $x = \dfrac ac$ and $y=\dfrac bc$.

Then we need to find rational soloutions $(x,y)$ to $x^2 + nxy + y^2 = 1$

[image]

We start with the particular solution $(x,y) = (-1,0)$ and "draw" the line 
$y = \dfrac uv(x+1)$, where $u,v$ are integers, through that point. It should intersect the hyperbola $x^2 + nxy + y^2 = 1$ at a rational point.

\begin{align}
   x^2 + nxy + y^2 &= 1 \\
   x^2 + \dfrac uvnx(x+1) + \dfrac{u^2}{v^2}(x+1)^2 &= 1 \\
   x &= \dfrac{v^2-u^2}{u^2+uvn+v^2} &\text{(We discarded $x=-1$.)} \\
   y &= u\dfrac{nu+2v}{u^2+nuv+v^2}
\end{align}

We get  $a^2+nab+b^2 = c^2$ where

\begin{align}
   a &= v^2-u^2 \\
   b &= nu^2+2uv \\
   c &= u^2+nuv+v^2
\end{align}

If $(a,b)$ is a solution, then so too is $(-a,-b)$, $(b,a)$, and $(-b,-a)$. So all solutions can be characterized as

$$\{a,b\} \in \{v^2-u^2, nu^2+2uv\}, \quad c = u^2+nuv+v^2$$

Comment: stereographic projection gives all rational solutions. It is possible to take integers with $\gcd(u,v)$ yet end up with $\gcd(a,b,c) \neq 1.$ So, we get all primitive integer triples if we say to divide $a,b,c$ by $\gcd(a,b,c).$ I do not know what to say about the apparent demand for $a,b > 0,$ not really natural. Oh, to ignore the gcd bit, it is commonly necessary to use several recipes such as you give. This will depend heavily on $n$

Comment: @WillJagy Could you elaborate on what you meant by "several recipes"?

Comment: @SchuHE The solutions of $a^2 + 6 b^2 = c^2$ quite naturally split  into recipes 
$$ a = u^2 - 6 v^2, \; \; b = 2 uv, \; \; c = u^2 + 6 v^2,  $$
$$ a = 2u^2 - 3 v^2, \; \; b = 2 uv, \; \; c = 2u^2 + 3 v^2  $$ In both, $c > 0.$ In the first, $c \neq 2 \pmod 3.$ In the second, $c \neq 1 \pmod 3.$

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks a lot. How did you find the different recipes (like did you use the same method except that you started with different solutions in each case), and how would you convince yourself that those recipes will cover all primitive solutions?

Comment: Is there a name for this method?

Comment: @SchuHE : It's got something to do with homogeneous coordinates and projective spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach this is to use Hilbert's theorem 90.

As in steven gregory's reply aim to solve
$$x^2+nxy+y^2=1$$
in the rationals. This is equivalent to
$$N\left(x+\frac{ny}2+\frac y2\sqrt{n^2-4}\right)=1$$
where $N$ is the norm map from $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{n^2-4})$
to $\Bbb Q$. By Hilbert 90, the norm $1$ elements of the
quadratic field are
$$\frac{u+v\sqrt{n^2-4}}{u-v\sqrt{n^2-4}}
=\frac{(u+v\sqrt{n^2-4})^2}{u^2-(n^2-4)v^2}$$
for rational $u$, $v$ not both zero. We can now grind out
general formulae for $x$ and $y$, which will be equivalent
to steven gregory's

Comment: Thanks for putting the problem and solution into a more number theoretic framework.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this equation has a lot of formulas for the solution. Because it is symmetrical.

Write the formula can someone come in handy. the equation:

$$Y^2+aXY+X^2=Z^2$$

Has a solution:

$$X=as^2-2ps$$

$$Y=p^2-s^2$$

$$Z=p^2-aps+s^2$$

more:

$$X=(4a+3a^2)s^2-2(2+a)ps-p^2$$

$$Y=(a^3-8a-8)s^2+2(a^2-2)ps+ap^2$$

$$Z=(2a^3+a^2-8a-8)s^2+2(a^2-2)ps-p^2$$

more:

$$X=(a+4)p^2-2ps$$

$$Y=3p^2-4ps+s^2$$

$$Z=(2a+5)p^2-(a+4)ps+s^2$$

more:

$$X=8s^2-4ps$$

$$Y=p^2-(4-2a)ps+a(a-4)s^2$$

$$Z=-p^2+4ps+(a^2-8)s^2$$

In the equation:  $$X^2+aXY+bY^2=Z^2$$ there is always a solution and one of them is quite simple.

$$X=s^2-bp^2$$

$$Y=ap^2+2ps$$

$$Z=bp^2+aps+s^2$$

$p,s$ - integers asked us.